# Select Element + jQuery

Tags: jquery

I used to have a text input at #element_3, where you may type in a number, and a function is run on that number, and the results are outputted dynamically to parts of the page.

I've changed that text input into a dropdown menu, but I don't know what to change in my JS code so that it works. I hope I've explained enough.

Here's my code - http://slexy.org/view/s2cwHc5do2

**Bold**
It seems my problem lies in this line:

```
$('#element_3').bind('keydown keyup keypress', calcPrice);
```

It would run the function when something was typed in, hence the keydown keyup keypress. But how do I make it work if there is no typing, but just a select element?

Comment: In the future, please don't refer to a `select` element as a "dropdown menu". They are not the same, as a dropdown menu usually refers to a [CSS menu with hover effects](http://purecssmenu.com/).

Comment: $('#element_3').bind('change', calcPrice);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#element_3").change(function() { whetever you want in the function });
```

check out the jquery docs on change, they use the .change() function when a select has a value changed

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1):

try this `$('#element_3').bind('change', calcPrice);`

although hard to say if your `calcPrice` function has been re-factored to handle selection rather than input

Answer (score 0):

@Andrei Korchagin: Working example -- http://jsfiddle.net/Mvwuq/

Just add `change` to your `bind`:

```
$('#element_3').bind('change keydown keyup keypress', calcPrice);
```